# Pass variable between python scripts on different computers.

Tags: python, networking, network-programming

Im new to programing. I want to know if there is a way to send a variable created on one computer in python to another computer running another python script on the same network. Basically lets say when the Variable is equal to 5 i want the other script to print 5

Answer (score -4, accepted):

try use socket an pickle, pickle will transform the variable into a string, then you can recover the object on other server

just the main functions, this code doesn't work alone

```
socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((host, port))
conn, addr = sock.accept()
conn.sendall(pickle.dumps({'somedictionary':data}))
```

recover data with

```
dict=pickle.loads(bufferreceived)
```

Comment: it don't means that it's not for network.. just to do not accept data from untrusted hosts with pickle because it can be anything... if you know from where you are receiving data it's not a problem, and... some one who is learning basic things probably will write something truly insecure too...

Comment: Where's the trust in this answer? Where's the warning about the danger of using this code? I *hope* the person who asked the question went and read the pickle documentation after reading this answer and saw the warning for themself but it's irresponsible to give this answer without duplicating that warning. On top of this "I want to send the number 5 over the network" is a bad reason to expose yourself up to these problems. It's true you *might* want to send pickles over a network but only if you have a harder problem than this.  For something this easy the risk is not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this would be through web services.  Essentially you get ComputerB listening on a port (such as 80, 81, 8100, etc) and have your script on ComputerA talk to it over http.

You can use a simple framework such as [web.py](http://webpy.org/) or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) hosted in a web server to invoke some Python code that sets this variable.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends of your technical requirements, program architecture etc. But basically i could recommend you to use some kind of message queue service to communicate between your applications. RabbitMQ, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ZeroMQ](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall).

> ØMQ (also known as ZeroMQ, 0MQ, or zmq) looks like an embeddable
>   networking library but acts like a concurrency framework. It gives you
>   sockets that carry atomic messages across various transports like
>   in-process, inter-process, TCP, and multicast. You can connect sockets
>   N-to-N with patterns like fan-out, pub-sub, task distribution, and
>   request-reply.